# MySQL: User access and DB overwriting

Tags: mysql

```
mysql -u someuser -DB somedb -H someip -c
```

This is the command I used from my shell to connect to a db. Now assume a "somedb" database was already there.

I am told my userid has just read access. So, what will happen on using this command? Will the old "somedb" be overwritten by a new "somedb"?

please reply soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have read only privilege, nothing will get overwritten.

```
mysql -u someuser -DB somedb -H someip -c
```

Using above command, you are just connecting to database. There will not be over-written anything by just connecting to database. nor anything will be deleted whether you use account with read-only privileges or full privileges.

Remember that database names are always unique on the same host.

Refer https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connecting.html for mysql database connection.

Comment: so, otherwise everything would get deleted?